# Calling a row with highest ID AND fulfilling a condition

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I'm trying to update a table called "Autentikasi". I want to update the row using form with two condition. It needs to have the same NRP AND also have the highest ID.

```
Patch(
Autentikasi,
First(  Filter(
        Autentikasi,
        And(Title = InputNRP.Text, First(Sort(Autentikasi, ID,Descending)))
```

[I've tried this method but it says Invalid Argument (Record). Expecting a Boolean value instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTGE2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use 2nd parameter of Patch function like this:

```
First(
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            Autentikasi,
            Title = InputNRP.Text
        ),
        "ID",
        SortOrder.Descending
    )
)
```

**Full Example**:

```
Patch(
    Autentikasi,
    First(
        SortByColumns(
            Filter(
                Autentikasi,
                Title = InputNRP.Text
            ),
            "ID",
            SortOrder.Descending
        )
    ),
    {
        Title: "List item Title"
    }
)
```